# How to get the latest value for a group

Tags: c#, sql, subquery

I am getting 15 rows from the query given below and the values obtained are also shown in the figure below

```
SELECT * FROM [SS_MatrixLearners] 
WHERE ssml_Id_learnercourse=7390 and ssml_id_matrix = 29 and ssml_Id_topic=47 
order by SSML_Id_LevelKey, SSML_Id_LevelValue
```

[image: query result]
With all these values I also want a single value of `SSML_CompletedByUserName` which has the latest date in the `SSML_CompletionDate` column.
Please help me how can I get that value. FYI I am using this in web forms using c#

Comment: So not really a c# question, more SQL for which ever DB type you're using question..   What have you tried

Comment: C# was mentioned just because we can add also add filter after getting values in the DataSet, I also tried that but not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the following solution.

> SELECT * into #temp FROM 
>   ( SELECT * FROM [SS_MatrixLearners] ORDER BY SSML_ID_LevelKey, SSML_Id_LevelValue) As rn
>   FROM [SS_MatrixLearners] where ssml_Id_learnercourse = 7390 and ssml_id_matrix = 29 and ssml_Id_topic = 47) t
>   WHERE rn = 1 
>   Update #temp SET SSML_CompletedByUserName = (select top 1 ISNULL(SSML_CompletedByUserName,'')
>   From [SS_MatrixLearners] 
>   WHERE ssml_Id_learnercourse=7390 and ssml_id_matrix = 29 and ssml_Id_topic=47
>   ORDER by SSML_CompletionDate desc 
>   )
>   SELECT * from #temp order by SSML_Id_LevelKey, SSML_Id_LevelValue  DROP table #temp

It would be nice if some optimize query can be written.